# How to read file client-side without using a file input?

Tags: javascript, file, client-side

I'm struggling to know how to read a file (client-side) in JS without using a file input, as I only need to read a local file in my project.

What I want to achieve is to get the content from a .less file in order to put it into a parser of some kind (I need to access its content in a javascript file).

I cannot use "fs" as I'm not using node, but I don't seem to be able to use the FileReader API either as it needs a Blob object which would be obtained by the file input.

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: You will either have to use `<input type="file"> ` (what you do not want to) or to serve it somewhere on the web and include it as asset. Ideally you host your file together with your js app which needs to get served anyways. When serving it somewher download it via HTTP request.

Comment: You can't read random files from the server or the filesystem, it would be a serious security breach. The only option you have here is to wrap your code in plain text on a js file and include it in your HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

client side doesn't have access to manage file system, you can read file with input but cannot write or delete from client side. it is only possible with a backend application written in node js or java, from their you can expose those services and call it from client side through http requests.